# Is there an easy way to get a Unix timestamp from an SQL timestamp in php?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, timestamp

My database table has a column that contains SQL timestamps (eg. 2009-05-30 19:43:41). I need the Unix timestamp equivalent (an integer) in my php program.

```
$posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY Created DESC");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($posts);
echo $array[Created];
```

Where it now echoes the SQL timestamp, I want a Unix timestamp. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) will happily take a SQL timestamp and convert it to UNIX time:

```
echo strtotime($array['Created']);
```

Note that it is bad practice to not use quotes around your array keys. [According to the docs](http://us.php.net/types.array):

> Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, $foo['bar'] is correct, while $foo[bar] is not.
>
> This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an undefined constant (bar) rather than a string ('bar' - notice the quotes). PHP may in future define constants which, unfortunately for such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.

Comment: I wish I could give you an extra +1 for the array key comment.

Answer (score 1):

Given a regular datetime field, you can do this in query with the MySQL function [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)():

```
$posts = mysql_query("SELECT *
                             , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Created)
                      FROM     Posts
                      ORDER BY Created DESC");
```

you also should know that the PHP function [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) returns both numeric associative keys for a query result. I find this redundant, so I like to be more more specific and use:

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($posts, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Also, and as @Paolo Bergantino indicated, quoting your echo would be a good decision:

```
echo $array['Created'];
```

One last comment, you're using "SELECT *" -- [it is worth reading discussion on the pros and cons of "SELECT *" syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select).

Comment: i prefer mysql_fetch_assoc instead of passing the 2nd argument to mysql_fetch_array

Comment: I'd definitely opt for this method, personally.  strtotime() is awesome, but it doesn't always work (some date strings are ambiguous).  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), on the other hand, is guaranteed to work.

Comment: strtotime is guaranteed to work on MySQL date/datetime/timestamp fields.

Comment: ...As long as they fall within the range representable by a unix timestamp: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#73601

For the purposes of this question, that's sufficient, but for more general use, it's good to be wary of the limitations of strtotime()

Comment: Another limitation of strtotime is that there can be differences with regards to timezone. strtotime is "guaranteed to work" on MySQL datetime fields, but the results may vary based on the offset of the timezone of the database versus the timezone of the server. In situations where precision is an issue, I would steer away from strtotime. Don't get me wrong, I *love* strtotime, but as Frank Farmer said, be wary of its limitations.