# How do I evaluate a timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

For a while I had been using a raw MySQL NOW() function to record the time/date in my MySQL DB until I realized the host's timezone variable was three hours ahead of PST. I've fixed this using `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)`, but now I have a ton of timestamps that are three hours ahead, and all future timestamps that are the showing the correct time.

Is there a PHP function to evaluate timestamps recorded before I made the fix so I can offset them when they display in my admin utility?

For example:

```
if($timestamp < 2012-02-16 21:57:18) {
    $timestamp - 3 hours;
}
```

Comment: `($timestamp < strtotime('2012-02-16 21:57:18'))` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: (assuming your PHP `$timestamp` is a UNIX timestamp from PHP, rather than a datetime string from MySQL)`

Comment: What about `UPDATE table SET timestamp = DATE_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 3 HOUR) WHERE timestamp < '2012-02-16 21:57:18'` to bring your database values in sync again. You certainly don't want to deal with this in application code.

Comment: @deceze and Michael Y U NO WRITE THEM AS ANSWERS.

Comment: @deceze Ok, this was actually the answer I was looking for, I just didn't think it could be done in SQL. Small minded of me.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper Because these questions get asked over and over. Most of the time, (I can only speak for myself), I'm searching for appropriate duplicates and then voting to close.

Comment: @Michael - true. question's fault, not answer anyway.

Comment: @the Because it's not what was asked, and because that would require me to further go into best practices about handling timezones between application and database side, which I don't really want to get into right now. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to get a Unix timestamp from an SQL timestamp in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936917/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-a-unix-timestamp-from-an-sql-timestamp-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Timestamp (offset by 3 hours behind)

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($row['timestamp_column_name'])-(3*60*60));
```

Create a second column in your table (perhaps?) and store the offset time - perhaps call it the admin time OR store the admin time offset from the system's time OR you can set the timezone PHP should use using something like the options mentioned here: [PHP timezone not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208666/php-timezone-not-set) .

Comment: I have to give this one credit because it answered my initial, misguided, question.

Answer (score 1):

the magical function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does all the work for you.  seriously check it out for adding, manipulating and even reading human readable forms of dates.  Then the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function is good for formatting it back into any form.

Answer (score 0):

For many input formats, [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) is the way to go. However, its heuristical approach may lead to surprising results, so if you only want to parse a specific format, use [`strptime`](http://php.net/strptime).